# How to set left-handed mouse pointer?

Tags: mouse, pointers

Is there a way to set a left-handed mouse pointer in Ubuntu 13.04?

For those who don't know what left-handed mouse pointers are:

[image]

Comment: right-handed mousepointers don't work for you?!

Comment: It's possible on Windows, and now I'm used to them.

Comment: It was more work than I would have liked, but I wanted to show that you can do anything on linux :P 
Please see my answer.

Comment: You can download the cursor set that I created.

https://github.com/Microtribute/cursor-left-yaru

Make sure you give it a star :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not seem there are many left-handed cursor themes. You have the following options:

### comixcursors-lefthanded (ugly)

You have to install [comixcursors-lefthanded [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/comixcursors-lefthanded) and [gcursor [image: Install gcursor]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcursor) (gnome cursor theme managing software). Although `gcursor` doesn't seem to do install the theme for me it is useful to see what a cursor theme looks like.

[image: gcursor]

The theme *ComixCursors-LH-White-Small* looks the most decent, so let's pick that one

**Installation**
First we need to add an extra line to the themes `index.themes` file. All themes are located in `/usr/share/icons`, and for the *ComixCursors-LH-White-Small* theme we need to do

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/icons/ComixCursors-LH-White-Small/index.theme
```

This file looks like this:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name = Comix Cursor LH White Small Bold
Comment = The left-handed Comix Cursors - White Small Bold
Example = default
```

Now we need to add the following line at the bottom (of course if you pick another theme, you should write the name of the other theme)

```
Inherits = ComixCursors-LH-White-Small
```

Now save and close the file.

On Ubuntu the utility `update-alternatives` manages the cursor themes, so we need to tell it about this new theme we want to use, execute

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/ComixCursors-LH-White-Small/index.theme 91
sudo update-alternatives --set x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/ComixCursors-LH-White-Small/index.theme
```

Now if you log out and log in again, you should have your new cursors.

**Note:**
You can use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

to change between the installed cursor themes.

### Modifying the default (DMZ-White) theme (beautiful)

The above approach works but the cursors are ugly, however you can also modify the default theme. The cursors that you use most are the normal pointer and the hand (which appears if you hover over a link):

[image: left_ptr] 
[image: hand2]

which are `/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/left_ptr` and `/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/hand2`.

The *DMZ-White* theme also provides a pointer that points to the right, and I made my own mirrored hand using [gimp [image: Install gimp]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp) (see note at the end):

[image: right_ptr] [image: hand3]

The pointer is `/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/right_ptr`, and mirrored hand is called `hand3` and I made it available on mediafire (if you follow the instructions below, you will download it automatically to the correct directory).

Now we need to replace these cursors. First go to the *DMZ-White* cursor directory

```
cd /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/
```

Then download the `hand3` cursor

```
sudo wget http://www.mediafire.com/download/v45c56ewol1k140/hand3
```

Now backup the original `left_ptr` and `hand2` files

```
sudo mv left_ptr left_ptr_orig
sudo mv hand2 hand2_orig
```

Now let the new `left_ptr` and `hand2` point to the `right_ptr` and `hand3` files

```
sudo ln -s right_ptr left_ptr
sudo ln -s hand3 hand2
```

Now if you log out and log in again, you should have your new (beautiful) cursors.

---

**Note: Editing cursor files using gimp**
You can edit cursor files (and make your own cursor theme :) ) using [gimp [image: Install gimp]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp) which is a free alternative to Photoshop. If you want to save your file choose *Export to* and then pick *X11 Mouse Cursor*. This will save your file with the `.xmc` extension, but you can simply remove the extension.

Comment: You should just push this as a patch into `dmz-cursor-theme` package or email them to one of the devs to do.

Comment: It would help all left handed users if this was part of Ubuntu.

Comment: You can download the cursor set that I created.

https://github.com/Microtribute/cursor-left-yaru

Make sure you give it a star :)

Answer (score 2):

### In Ubuntu 15.10

```
sudo apt-get install comixcursors-lefthanded gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-tweak-tool
```

**Appearance > Cursor Theme**

To search for alternative cursor themes:

```
apt-cache search cursor | grep cursor | grep left
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You have to install [comixcursors-lefthanded [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/comixcursors-lefthanded) and [gcursor [image: Install gcursor]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcursor) (gnome cursor theme managing software).

Open gcursor an choose what cursor theme do you wish.

To set your mouse click to left-handed, see the end of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/299051/147044).

Comment: Yep, this is the extremely ugly theme I mentioned in my comments...

Comment: No longer works

Comment: You can download the cursor set that I created.

https://github.com/Microtribute/cursor-left-yaru

Answer (score 0):

You can download the cursor set that I created.

https://github.com/Microtribute/cursor-left-yaru

Make sure you give it a star :)