# Single click has changed to double click after changing mouse battery

Tags: 22.04, mouse

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on an HP-15 Notebook. For years I've been using single click to do pretty much everything, e.g. move from tab to tab in Chrome or Firefox, or select fields in online forms. Since changing the mouse battery this afternoon all that has changed. I have to double click on every application, even the online games that I play, which is driving my autistic head up the wall, as I hate change, and especially on my computer settings. Just about every search for such problems is dominated by the file managers, which I'm not that interested in. So how do I restore the mouse setting to my preferred behaviour, I'm guessing that it's fairly simple, but I just can't see the wood for the trees?

Comment: I'm not sitting in front of my system at the moment, but I can't imagine it being much different than the answer here https://askubuntu.com/q/299048/231142